# Using proxy on docker-compose in server

Tags: docker, proxy, docker-compose

When i run `sudo docker-compose build` i get

```
Building web
Step 1/8 : FROM python:3.7-alpine
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: error parsing HTTP 403 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<html><body><h1>403 Forbidden</h1>\nSince Docker is a US company, we must comply with US export control regulations. In an effort to comply with these, we now block all IP addresses that are located in Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Republic of Crimea, Sudan, and Syria. If you are not in one of these cities, countries, or regions and are blocked, please reach out to https://support.docker.com\n</body></html>\n\n"
```

I need to set proxy for `docker-compose` for build

things i have tried:

looking at https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-the-docker-client

- i have tried setting `~/.docker/config.json`

  ```
  {
   "proxies":
   {
    "default":
    {
     "httpProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:9278"
    }
   }
  }
  ```
- tried with `--env` argument
- tried setting proxy variables on the server with no result
- i also have tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36084324/4626485)

  ```
  services:
    myservice:
      build:
        context: .
        args:
          - http_proxy
          - https_proxy
          - no_proxy
  ```

  but i get this on `version: '3.6'`

  ```
  Unsupported config option for services.web: 'args'
  ```

these settings seem to be set on docker and not docker-compose

i also don't need to set any proxy on my local device (i don't want to loose portability if possible)

```
docker-compose version 1.23.1, build b02f1306
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must be from restricted countries which are banned by docker (from [403](https://httpstatuses.com/403) status code). only way is to use proxies in your docker service.

> [Service]
>
> ...
>
> Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/
> HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/"
>
> ...

after that you should issue:

```
$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: you can find service file address by looking at `systemctl status docker`

Answer (score 1):

Include proxy details for each service in docker-compose.yml file, the sample configuration looks as below mentioned. Restart the docker and then run "docker-compose build" again. You might also run "docker-compose ps" to see if all the services mentioned in the compose file running successfully.

```
services:
  <service_name>:
    image: 
    hostname: 
    container_name: 
    ports:
    environment:      
      HTTP_PROXY: 'http://host:port'
      HTTPS_PROXY: 'http://host:port'
      NO_PROXY: 'localhost, *.test.lan'
```

Answer (score 0):

1: edit resolve.conf in linux, add [ip](https://shecan.ir/) to the top of line in `resolv.conf`

```
nameserver {type ip}
```

2: use a poxy and create an account in docker hub (https://hub.docker.com/)

3:login into docker

```
sudo docker login
user:
password:
```

4: if you have problem try step 3 again

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an env file which you put proxy settings in
/usr/local/etc/myproxy.env

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.mydomain.net:3128
HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.mydomain.net:3128
```

Then run docker-compose with something like:

```
docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml --env-file /usr/local/etc/myproxy.env up
```