# How to use local proxy settings in docker-compose

Tags: proxy, docker-compose, redmine

I am setting up a new server for our Redmine installation, since the old installation was done by hand, which makes it difficult to update everything properly. I decided to go with a Docker image but am having trouble starting the docker container due to an error message. The host is running behind a proxy server, which I think, is causing this problem, as everything else such as wget, curl, etc. is working fine.

Error message:

```
Pulling redmine (redmine:)...
ERROR: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp 34.206.236.31:443: connect: connection refused
```

I searched on Google about using Docker/Docker-Compose with a proxy server in the background and found a few websites where people had the same issue but none of these really helped me with my problem.

I checked with the Docker documentation and found a guide but this does not seem to work for me: https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/

I also found an answered question here on StackOverflow: [Using proxy on docker-compose in server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53477114/using-proxy-on-docker-compose-in-server) which might be the solution I am after but I am unsure where exactly I have to put the solution. I guess the person means the docker-compose.yml file but I could be wrong.

This is what my docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

redmine:
 image: redmine
 restart: always
 ports:
   - 80:3000
 environment:
   REDMINE_DB_MYSQL: db
   REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD: SECRET_PASSWORD

db:
image: mysql:5.7
restart: always
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: SECRET_PASSWORD
  MYSQL_DATABASE: redmine
```

I expect to run the following command without the above error message

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Answer (score 56):

I did a bit more research and seem to have used better key words because I have found my solution now. I wanted to share the solution with everyone, in case someone else may ever need it.

- Create a folder for configuring the Docker service through systemd

  `mkdir /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d`
- Create a service configuration file at `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf` and put the following in the newly created file

```
[Service]
 # NO_PROXY is optional and can be removed if not needed
 # Change proxy_url to your proxy IP or FQDN and proxy_port to your proxy port
 # For Proxy servers that require username and password authentication, just add the proper username and password to the URL. (see example below)

 # Example without authentication
 Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy_url:proxy_port" "NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8"

 # Example with authentication
 Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy_url:proxy_port" "NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8"

 # Example for SOCKS5

Environment="HTTP_PROXY=socks5://proxy_url:proxy_port" "NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8"
```

- Reload systemctl so that new settings are read

  `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
- Verify that docker service Environment is properly set

  `sudo systemctl show docker --property Environment`
- Restart docker service so that it uses updated Environment settings

  `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Now you can execute the `docker-compose` command on your machine without getting any `connection refused` error messages.

Comment: How can I enter the password for the proxy?

Comment: @PrasanthGanesan Depending on the protocol you use, you could use one of the following URLs: 

`http://username:password@proxy_url:proxy_port`
`https://username:password@proxy_url:proxy_port`

Comment: Thanks to @PrasanthGanesan for bringing up the username/password authentication. I edited my original post and added an example of such authentication in the `http-proxy.conf`

Comment: SOCKS5 can also be used: `HTTP_PROXY=socks5://proxy_url:proxy_port`.

Comment: Please note that the proxy settings need trailing slashes at the end! @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71666466/4666528

Answer (score 11):

For the proxy server which requires username and password for authentication: Apart from adding the credentials in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf`, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54220188/8195166) answer, I also had to add the same to the Dockerfile. Following is a snippet from the Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ENV http_proxy http://username:password@proxy_url:proxy_port
ENV https_proxy http://username:password@proxy_url:proxy_port

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    bla bla bla ...
```