# Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers) ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu

Since Yesterday, out of nowhere I'm facing this issue. I cannot pull any image or cannot login to docker. I've been following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766682/docker-error-response-from-daemon-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2-net-ht) solution for resolve, but none of the changes worked for me. I'm not behind any proxy and on my local machine.
These are the docker version details:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.17
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.11
 Git commit:        100c701
 Built:             Mon Jun  6 23:02:57 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.17
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.17.11
  Git commit:       a89b842
  Built:            Mon Jun  6 23:01:03 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.6
  GitCommit:        10c12954828e7c7c9b6e0ea9b0c02b01407d3ae1
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.2
  GitCommit:        v1.1.2-0-ga916309
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Comment: Is this a docker issue or a network issue? What happens if you `curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/`?

Comment: This is the output. ```{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}``` . I know that I'm not connected to docker, but my internet is working fine.

Comment: Have you tried restarting just the docker engine (`systemctl restart docker`)?

Comment: yes I restarted it, still the error persists.